# Are images of players which are surrounded by google ads means commercial use?

Tags: legal

I wanted to know if I use a player's image but I am not using it in any product or service my website is featured by adsense so that means a players image will be surrounded by ads which are not set up by me particularly Does that mean I am using the image commercially?

Comment: Use the image for what?? players of what? Where did you get these images from? Please [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Legal questions are generally off topic here. Ask your lawyer instead.

Comment: Laws differ a lot across the globe. Especially copyright law (US copyright law is really inclusive if i compare to my local law, in usa everything is copyrightable by default. Locally not so much.) So at minimum anybody who could answer would need to know the legal stuff in your precedent. But generally speaking everything you do is commercial unless it fits certain exceptions (which are different in different countries). It does not matter whether you consider it commercial or not.

Comment: "Commercial use" means **anything** which is designed to advertise or promote you or your services (like a business web site). Or use in *anything* which can be purchased or obtained as a promotional item by clients/customers. Basically, if you don't make *anything* from the use it *may* not be commercial use. But a web site, containing advertising, is absolutely "commercial use".